# liquibaseDiffChangelog gradle task erring out with java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to generate liquibase change log for spring boot microservice with embedded postgressql backend (disk based). Command below

```
./gradlew -PexcludeLog4j=true liquibaseDiffChangelog -PrunList=diffLog -PliquibaseTimestamp=1620929423 -Purl="jdbc:h2:mem:~/workspace/test/testms/build/h2db"
```

Always erring out with

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply
> JDBC connections
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)
> at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateEjb3Database.buildMetadataFromPath(HibernateEjb3Database.java:59)
> at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.buildMetadata(HibernateDatabase.java:143)
> at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.setConnection(HibernateDatabase.java:83)
> at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(DatabaseFactory.java:121)
> at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:141)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:96)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.createReferenceDatabaseFromCommandParams(Main.java:2107)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1511)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:367)
> at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:366)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:196)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
> at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:145)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:196)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:158) BEST PRACTICE: The changelog generated by
> diffChangeLog/generateChangeLog should be inspected for correctness
> and completeness before being deployed. Liquibase command
> 'diffChangeLog' was executed successfully.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generating incremental diff, we need to run task `liquibaseUpdate` first before `liquibaseDiffChangelog`

Added the below extension

```
task generateLiquibaseChangelog {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'liquibaseUpdate'
    dependsOn 'liquibaseDiffChangeLog'

    tasks.findByName('liquibaseUpdate').mustRunAfter 'clean'
    tasks.findByName('liquibaseDiffChangeLog').mustRunAfter 'liquibaseUpdate'

    project.ext."excludeLog4j"="true"
    project.ext."runList"="diffLog"
    project.ext."liquibaseTimestamp"=getTimestamp()
}

def getTimestamp() {
    return new Date().format('yyyyMdHHms')
}
```